# Plotly Heatmap: specify a hovertemplate for each data point

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

For plotly Heatmap, how should I specify a different hovertemplate for each data point? If I specify hovertemplate as a 2D array, it does not show any hover information.

```
data = [[1, 2, 3],
      [1, 2, 3],
      [1, 2, 3]]
fig = go.Figure(go.Heatmap(
                z=data,
                hovertemplate=data,
))
fig
```

Comment: what information do you want to display on the hovertemplate? if you get rid of the argument `hovertemplate=data`, the hovertemplate will display x, y, z on each rectangular tile

Comment: @DerekO I want to hide the hover box for some specific rectangular tiles, depending on the value of that tile.